# PS for $4u_{n+1}-u_n = 5\cdot4^{-n}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How do you find particular solutions for:

$$4u_{n+1}-u_n = 5\cdot4^{-n} \text{ ?}$$

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: $z$-transform might be a good help

Comment: Is this a recursive equation or a differential equation in a different syntax?  What is a "particular solution" ?

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying both sides by $4^n$ will give you 
$$4^{n+1}u_{n+1}-4^nu_n=5.$$
Let $x_n=4^nu_n$. The following is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_n=v_n+ a4^{-n}n$ where $a$ is to be determined. You can plug this in, and choose $a=5$ to cancel out the $4^{-n}$ terms and only have recursive relation on $v_{n+1}$ and $v_n$.

Comment: That does not work, because 4^(-n) is a solution of the homogeneous recurrence.

Comment: I have an $n$ there: $u_n=v_n + 5n4^{-n}$. :-)

Comment: @zyx I have an $n$ there: $u_n=v_n + 5n4^{-n}$.